# Hiding jQuery Tabs

Tags: php, jquery, yii

Is there a way to hide an empty jQuery tab?

Specifically I am using Yii's CJuiTabs and pulling the tab content from a db.

If that content does not exist in the db I do not want a tab displayed at all for that.  Can this be done?

Including CJuiTabs in Yii:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs', array(
    'tabs'=>array(
        'StaticTab 1'=>'Content for tab 1',
        'StaticTab 2'=>array('content'=>'Content for tab 2', 'id'=>'tab2'),
        // panel 3 contains the content rendered by a partial view
        'AjaxTab'=>array('ajax'=>$ajaxUrl),
    ),
    // additional javascript options for the tabs plugin
    'options'=>array(
        'collapsible'=>true,
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the stuff generated in PHP

```
foreach ($dbContents as $id => $content) {
  if (!$content) continue;
  $tabs[] = Array('id' => 'tab-'.$id, 'content' => $content)
}

$this->widget(....., array('tabs'=>$tabs));
```

PS: Written on my mobile, Code could be a bit more sophisticated :)